# Multiple File Uploading (File Restriction error)

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload multiple files in 1 go. I have successfully tested the code on a single file upload (removed the for each loop) then its all working. File is uploading and checking file size/file type. But when I tried to put in a for loop to be able to do multiple files, its return "***This file extension is not allowed, please upload a JPEG or PNG file***"

HTML Code:

```
    <form action="fileUpload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr><td>File 1</td> <td><input name="file_upload[]" type="file" class="multi"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>File 2</td> <td><input name="file_upload[]" type="file" class="multi"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td></td> <td> <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"><input type="reset"> </td> </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

PHP code:

```
    foreach ($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {

            $rootDir = getcwd(); // get current working directory

            $uploadDirectory = "/uploads/";     

            $fileExtensions = ['jpeg','jpg','png', 'pdf', 'docx',]; // Get all the file extensions

            $fileType = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'][$key];
            // $fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));
            $fileExtension = pathinfo($_FILES["file_upload"]["tmp_name"][$key]);

            $uploadPath = $rootDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

            // echo $uploadPath;


    }

?>
```

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` you will see the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
$fileExtension = pathinfo($_FILES["file_upload"]["tmp_name"][$key]);
```

to :

```
$fileExtension = pathinfo($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"][$key]);
$fileExtension = $fileExtension['extension'];
```

Previously your code checks for the temporary files extension.